# Is there more elegant way to implode data to query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, implode

I am going to ask because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803969/should-i-rate-limit-or-reduce-my-database-queries/6804006#6804006) answer.

My code looks like

```
<?php
$lines = file('file.txt');
$count = count($lines);
$i = 0;
$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ";
foreach($lines as $line){
    $i++;
    if ($count == $i) {
        $query .= "('".$line."')";
    }
    else{
        $query .= "('".$line."'),";
    }
}
echo $query;
```

is there more elegant way to do this/function in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ( $lines AS $line )  
{  
  $query[] = "($line)";  
}  

echo  "INSERT INTO table VALUES " . implode(",",$query);
```

is how to do it with implode but i think AlienWebguy's is better

Comment: this is what I was looking exactly.

Comment: +1, this is much cleaner than hacking together a string and then trimming it.  However, it can still be improved.  `file()` returns an array already, so you can just `echo 'INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (' . join(') (', file('file.txt')) . ');'` (assuming that you know there is at least one line in the file).

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES ';
$query .= "('" . implode("'), ('", $lines) . "')";
```

**UPD**:

For 2 fields it could look like (I suppose you use php5+):

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES ';

$lines = array(array(1,2), array(3,4));
$query .= "('" . implode("'), ('", array_map(function($i) { return "'" . implode("', '", $i) . "'"; }, $lines)) . "')";

var_dump($query);
```

Comment: How would I use this in case of more data? for example 2 DB fields?

Comment: @genesis: give an example of input data in the question please

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(file('file.txt') as $line){
    $query .= "('".$line."'),";
}
echo "INSERT INTO table VALUES " . rtrim($query,',');
```

Comment: well, I did use this too, I forgot it, though :) Thanks for reminiding it ! +1

Comment: I prefer this one as it is much more readable and it will be easier to work out what is happening when you look at it again in 6 months time. Clever code is good, readable code is better and clever, readable code is best :) . I've had enough of non-obvious code, especially my own! Anyway, +1

Comment: I disagree, the implode approach is clearer to read, more elegant and more efficient.

Comment: To each his own, I suppose. I actually prefer zerkms to my own haha. Wish I'd thought of it myself! :)

Answer (score 1):

LOAD DATA INFILE is better suited for this specific task: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html